# Make pedestrians divert to another queue if QueueTime Exceeds a preselected Value

Tags: queue, simulation, anylogic

Edited Version:
I'm actually modelling an airport check-in terminal. It works fine so far, but additional I'm still trying to implement a function, that allows my pedestrians not to enter the service-queue if the queue time exceeds a preselected value (e.g. already 15 Passengers in the queue) and therefore walks to some kind of backup Service that opens during this busy times.

Here is my approach:

1. Variable `QueueSize` returns permanently the actual Number of Passengers in the Queue.
2. Every time a ped enters the pedservice block `CheckInEco`, the function `waitingTime()` starts:

```
QueueSize = CheckInEco.size(); 
if (QueueSize > 15) CheckInEco.cancel(ped)
```

So, as soon as there are more than 15 Agents in the queue, number 16 should bypass and move to an alternate ServiceBlock, which I would connect to the ccl Port of the CheckInEco Service. But when building the model, I get this message: `ped cannot be resolved to a variable`?

According to Anylogic Help, it should be possible to use this `cancel - call`, but I'm not really experienced with it.. Maybe, someone can help me out?

[image: function waitingTime]

[image: screenshot Main]

[image: PedService CheckInEco]

Comment: You are already tracking the time spent in the queue. You can calculate the average also easily. Why not to use a simple selectOutput block whenever that threshold is reached and send the pedestrians to the backup service?

Comment: The method with the selectOutput block would be great and I also thought about it. But my problem is, how to retrieve the actualWaitingTime that is recorded in the DataSet?

Comment: I am not sure why you don't use normal variables instead of dataset?

Comment: I apparently thought too complicated. Is it basically possible, to continuously update a variable (e.g. actualWaitingTime) and use this as condition for the SelectOutput-Block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a select output block to prevent pedestrians from going into the service block if there are more than 16 pedestrians already in.

[image]

Your original question had to do with waiting time, you should follow the exact same approach. But with waiting time it gets more complicated since you don't want to take the average waiting time from the start of the simulation.... so you need to decide if you want to take the last 10 minutes, 1 hour etc and do you want to include the current waiting time of agents in the queue. Since this is the the questions anymore I am not going to add it here, perhaps ask a new question if this is still the case.

Comment: You are right, the variant with the number of passengers in the queue is much easier to implement than via the waiting time. I have tested this now and it works sufficiently accurate for my project. Thanks

Comment: Awesome. Remember to accept my answer if you found it helpful, and upvote if you found it worthy ;-)